# CollectionView does not support changes due to Different Thread In Dispatcher.Invoke()

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf

**I Saw Many Questions In StackOverFlow but they're doesn't Get this error In Dispatcher**

I'm Upgrading a Wpf App In Company , They Gave me a task for Game List on UI To Be Faster.

the app Design Pattern is **mvvm**.

I Developed 2 Section.

Section 1: Games Fetched From Database
Section 2: Regular Search On Pc.

Before This: Only Regular Search.

Here's My Code:

```
public async Task FindGameInBackground()
{
    await App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(HandleLaunchersAndGames); // Problem Here
        
    await App.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => Games = new (Games.OrderBy(x => x.Name)));
    GamesView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Games);
    ...
}
```

HandleLaunchersAndGames is okay but it's call AddGame method after filling the data

```
private Task AddGame(Game gameModel)
{
    var lGameModel = gameModel;
    if (!Games.Any(x => x.Name.Equals(lGameModel.Name)) ||
        !Games.Any(x => x.AId.Equals(lGameModel.AId)) ||
        Games.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(lGameModel.Name))
                .All(x => x.LauncherName != lGameModel.LauncherName))
    {

        bool threadAccess = App.Current.Dispatcher.Thread == Thread.CurrentThread;
        if (threadAccess)
        {
            Games.Add(lGameModel); // **I Get The Error Here.**
        }
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Games.Add(lGameModel));

    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Games Type:

```
public ObservableCollection<Game> Games
{
    get => _games ??= new ObservableCollection<Game>();
    set
    {
        _games = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

and it's binding in UI

i don't know why i get this error, i'm using Dispatcher and Invoke
in AddGame i'm checking the Thread Access but i get error after adding object

Comment: Even though `App.Current.Dispatcher.Thread == Thread.CurrentThread` returns `true`, it seems you're still on a different thread. What's the performance penalty if you always run `App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Games.Add(lGameModel))` instead of checking whether you're on the same thread? Anyway, your `if` there lacks `else`, I'd say.

Comment: Hello @Mike, it's Allocate everytime if i use Invoke, but it's not the problem beacuse i get error with Invoke too

Comment: Please post the minimal code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Hello @StephenCleary, Thanks For You're suggest,  I Minimalized my code please check again.

Comment: In my opinion, there are many pitfalls in such code. I really don't like accessing Dispatcher from Task. It is better to return the result from the Task and assign the result in synchronous code. But how to do this in your application is difficult to say. Since there is no understanding of the call chain of your asynchronous methods. The beginning of this chain must be in some synchronous code. Perhaps it is a command or an event. It would be great if you could upload the solution to GitHub and provide a link.

Comment: I also don’t understand why you copy the argument value into a local variable? `var lGameModel = gameModel;`

Comment: Instead of comparing threads you should use the `Dispatcher.CheckAccess(void) : bool` method. Please don't skip any code because you think it's not relevant. Show the **minimal code that is required to reproduce the issue**. Even the context of `FindGameInBackground` in order to know the execution context. Otherwise, a code review is pointless in general. Also don't use nested Dispatcher.Invoke calls. Unless you have to access UI elements (or DispatcherObjects in general) simply don't use the Dispatcher. Please provide a **minimal example that builds**, but that still reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided all the details that are necessary to give you accurate advice.
Therefore, I will show some abstract implementation of one of the possible options.

```cs
using Simplified;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Core2023.SO.HosseinSanjabian.Question77697304
{
    public record Game(string Name, int AId, string LauncherName)
    {
        public Game() : this(string.Empty, 0, string.Empty) { }

        public override string ToString() => $"{AId}: {Name} ({LauncherName})";
    }

    public class GamesViewModel
    {
        public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Game> Games { get; }
        private readonly ObservableCollection<Game> privateGames = new();

        private void AddGame(Game gameModel)
        {
                Thread.Sleep(5000); // Emulating some kind of delay in the execution method
                lock (((ICollection)privateGames).SyncRoot)
                    privateGames.Add(gameModel);
        }

        private async Task AddGameAsync(Game gameModel)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => AddGame(gameModel));
        }

        public RelayCommand<Game> AddGameCommand { get; }

        public GamesViewModel()
        {
            Games = new(privateGames);

            AddGameCommand = new(async game => await AddGameAsync(game));
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="Core2023.SO.HosseinSanjabian.Question77697304.GamesWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2023.SO.HosseinSanjabian.Question77697304"
        xmlns:cm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="GamesWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <local:GamesViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="games" Source="{Binding Games}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <cm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
        <local:Game x:Key="addidingGame"/>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <UniformGrid Rows="1">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource games}}"/>
        <UniformGrid Columns="1">
            <UniformGrid Columns="2" DataContext="{DynamicResource addidingGame}">
                <TextBlock Text="AID:"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding AId}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Name:"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="LauncherName:"/>
                 <TextBox Text="{Binding LauncherName}"/>
           </UniformGrid>
            <Button Content="Add Game"
                    Command="{Binding AddGameCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{DynamicResource addidingGame}"
                    Click="OnAddidingGame"/>
        </UniformGrid>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Core2023.SO.HosseinSanjabian.Question77697304
{
    public partial class GamesWindow : Window
    {
        public GamesWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GamesViewModel viewModel = (GamesViewModel) FindResource("vm");
            ICollection games = viewModel.Games;
            BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(games, games.SyncRoot);
        }

        private async void OnAddidingGame(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            Resources["addidingGame"] = new Game();
        }
    }
}
```